# most important usage in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

The key to their success is a warm,kind heart and, most important, self-acceptance.
What is the usage of "most important" in this sentence.
It means "most importantly" or " the most important key".
Next question is :
"The most important key" is only self-acceptance or both "a warm,kind heart and self-acceptance"?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the ***[most important](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/most-important)***  , that is ***the main*** aspect, to the achievement of thier  success is self-acceptance. A warm and kind heart is also part of the key to success, but it  is not so important as self-acceptance.